# Trying to add options to this script, not quite working

Tags: bash

I started with this script called wd:

```
cat "$@" | tr -cs '[:alpha:]' '\n' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' 
| sort | uniq -c | sort -n | awk '{print $2 " " $1}' | sort
```

That takes any number of files as input and prints a distribution of the words in the file like this:

```
wd file1 file2

blue 2
cat 3
the 5
yes 1
```

Now I'm trying to add 2 options to it: s and t. s causes the script to take an input file called stopwords, and deletes those words from the input file before making the distribution. t takes a number n as an argument and only outputs the top n words. Default is all words.

So, so far I have this script. Currently, my problem is when I try to use a -t 10 option for example, it tells me it cannot find the file 10, but it should be a number anyway, not a file. And, when I try to use the -s option, it simply does nothing, but does not output any error. I know this question isn't very specific, but I would appreciate any ideas on what's wrong.

```
#!/bin/bash

stopwords=FALSE
stopfile=""
topwords=0

while getopts s:t: option 
do
    case "$option"
    in
        s) stopwords=TRUE
        stopfile="$OPTARG";;
        t) topwords=$OPTARG;;
        \?) echo "Usage: wd [-s stopfile] [-t n] inputfile"
            echo "-s takes words in stopfile and removes them from inputfile"
            echo "-t means to output only top n words"
            exit 1;;
    esac
done

if [ "stopwords" = FALSE ]
then
    cat "$@" | tr -cs '[:alpha:]' '\n' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' 
| sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n $topwords | awk '{print $2 " " $1}' | sort
else
    cat "$@" | grep -v -f "$stopfile" |  tr -cs '[:alpha:]' '\n' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' 
| uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n $topwords | awk '{print $2 " " $1}' | sort
fi
```

Comment: `stopwords` in `if [ "stopwords" = FALSE ]` should be `$stopwords`?

Comment: And when you see problems with `bash` scripts, try to `bash -x /your/script` and you may easily find what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Usually after the `while getopts` loop you need to `shift $((OPTIND - 1))`. Following is an example I wrote before for both `ksh` and `bash`:

```
PROGNAME=$0

function _echo
{
    printf '%s\n' "$*"
}

function usage
{
    cat << END
usage: $PROGNAME [-a] [-b arg] [-h] file...
END

    exit $1
}

function parseargs
{
    typeset opt v

    [[ $# = 0 ]] && usage 1

    while getopts ":ab:h" opt "$@"; do
        case $opt in
            a)   _echo -$opt ;;
            b)   _echo -$opt $OPTARG ;;
            h)   usage ;;
            :)   _echo "! option -$OPTARG wants an argument" ;;
            '?') _echo "! unkown option -$OPTARG" ;;
        esac
    done
    shift $((OPTIND - 1))

    for v in "$@"; do
        _echo "$v"
    done
}

parseargs "$@"
```